# How to fix the width of TabPanes?

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am using the following ant design combo in React:

```
<Tabs type="card">
  <TabPane>...</TabPane>
</Tabs>
```

What is the easiest way to put custom CSS on the TabPane elements in React?
I would like to fix their widths but can't even put custom className on the TabPane as it gets lost once it gets to the DOM. Can't even wrap the `<TabPane>` into a `<div>` as `<Tabs>` accepts only `<TabPane>`s as children.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

OK, I think I got this:

```
import styles from './someCssComponent.css';

<Tabs type="card">
  <TabPane key={key} tab={<div className={styles.foo}></div>}>Yolo</TabPane>
</Tabs>
```

And then in the CSS module:

```
.foo { width: 60px; }
```

Answer (score 1):

looks like that option is not supported, but there is a style object for Tabbar, not sure if it's what you looking for...

```
<Tabs type="card" tabBarStyle={{color: 'red'}>
  <TabPane>...</TabPane>
</Tabs>
```

o overwrite css... We had to overwrite many of antd's css :(

Answer (score 0):

<Tabs type="card" tabBarStyle={{width:"200px"}}>

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).